# How to match exclamation mark (!) in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to match camel cased words beginning with `!` such as `!RedHat` contained in `$line`. I'm using `php 5.3.10-1ubuntu2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)`.

I'm trying following things:

- `$line = preg_replace(" !([A-Z])", " $1", $line);`

  - result: `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '!' found`
- `$line = preg_replace(" \!([A-Z])", " $1", $line);`

  - result: `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`
- `$line = preg_replace(" [!]([A-Z])", " $1", $line);`

  - result: `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '('`
- `$line = preg_replace(" [\!]([A-Z])", " $1", $line);`

  - result: `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '('`

How is the correct way to match `!` in  PHP regexp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use delimiters in your regex - non-alphanumeric, as the error message states:

```
$line = preg_replace("/ !([A-Z])/", " $1", $line);
```

Notice the `/` characters at the beginning and end of the regex string.

These don't have to be `/` - you could use `#` or even `!` - but if you use `!` then you'll need to escape the `!` char inside the regex itself.

Comment: you don't need to escape the `!`

Comment: @BartKiers Yes, I know - I just copied a random one of his options - turned out to be the second one.  I updated the answer now.

Comment: @OP please note that to use php's regex functions you have to enclose the expression with a "random" (self chosen) delimiter. This can be / (as in the example), but also &, *, or whatever. But pretty much any example found on the internet omits those enclosures (which is correct), so don't forget them :)

Comment: I wouldn't call them normal delimiters. I think PHP is the only language where regexes need to be inside strings *and* require delimiters. Everywhere else it's only one of the two.

Comment: @Joey: "normal" in a sense of PHP.  They don't have to be '/' - just need to be the same at the beginning and end and be non-alphanumeric.  There's nothing wrong with using '!' as a delimiter, but then you will need to escape it.  But I'm sure you know this.  I updated my answer

Comment: @giorgio you are absolutely correct.  It just happens that '/' is used most often.  I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
!\b([A-Z][a-z]*){2,}\b
```

Live preview:
http://regexr.com?30a95
(check global and multiline).

Comment: the word boundary in `!\b[A-Z]` can simply be omitted: there's always a `\b` between `!` and a letter. The OP's problem is the delimiters, which Aleks already mentioned in his answer.